# Specify Express middleware that always runs at the end?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Does `express` provide a way to specify that a middleware always runs at the end of the chain?

I want to create a pair of middleware functions, one at the start, and one at the end, which gather up analytics about the call.

I know I can do something like this:

```
app.use(entry);

app.get("/some-endpoint", (req, res, next) => {
  res.send("hello").end();
  next();
});

app.use(exit);
```

Where `entry()` and `exit()` are my middleware.

However, there are two things I don't like about this solution. First, is that `next()` has to be called or else the `exit()` middleware won't be used.

The other is that I would prefer to instead build a `Router` that can be used as one piece and just work. Something like:

```
// MyRouter.js
const router = () => Router()
  .use(entry)
  .use(exit);
export default router;

// myServer.js
import router from './MyRouter.js';
import express from 'express';

const app = express();
app.use(router());

app.get("/some-endpoint", (req, res) => {
  res.send("hello").end();
});
```

Being able to bundle it all up in to one thing that always runs would make it a lot more usable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the `res` object in Express wraps `http.ServerResponse`, you can attach a listener for the [`'finish'` event](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v9.x/docs/api/http.html#http_event_finish) in a middleware. Then when the response is "finished", `exit()` will be called as soon as the event fires.

```
// analyticMiddleware.js
const analyticMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
    // Execute entry() immediately
    // You'll need to change from a middleware to a plain function
    entry()

    // Register a handler for when the response is finished to call exit()
    // Just like entry(), you'll need to modify exit() to be a plain function
    res.once('finish', () => exit)

    // entry() was called, exit() was registered on the response return next()
    return next()
}

module.exports = analyticMiddleware
```

---

```
// myServer.js
import analytics from './analyticMiddleware.js';
import express from 'express';

const app = express();
app.use(analytics);

app.get("/some-endpoint", (req, res) => {
  res.send("hello").end();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up with something very similar to this, though I kept `entry()` and `exit()` middleware functions and chained them with `Router()` as above, mainly for cleanness of code. Functionally it's the same as what you gave.